# RJulia - sharing large data structures without copying them

Tags: r, julia, large-data

I would like to call R functions from within Julia on very large data structures.

I understand that PyCall can share variables between Julia and Python without copying them.

I  also understand that as of August 2019 variables still needed to be copied when transferring between R and Julia (https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/114).

Q1: Is there any way to call R functions in Julia without having to copy data structures?

Q2: Does Apache Arrow work with RJulia?

Q3: If there is a way to transfer variables without copying them, does this apply to all data types? Numerical array, categorical array, time array, table, list, and dictionary?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems like a great idea but could be challenging. (Part of Julia's attraction it that it's supposed to be a language in which one can do *everything* in a high-level but efficient way, thus avoiding the friction of dealing with more than one language ...)

Comment: That would be indeed ideal. However, there are a couple of packages only written in R that I need to use but would like to use Julia for the rest of my program